# No consigo que me muestre el *ngFor

Tags: ngfor

Estoy realizando un app que coja los datos de las issues de Github y mostrarlos en una lista.

He realizado ya el service y el model, y veo el array en consola con la petición GET.

Pero cuando lanzo el ngFor me sale esto en el DOM

Entiendo que es algo que no estoy haciendo bien pero soy nueva en esto de angular y no veo el error. Si alguien podría ayudarme seria de gran ayuda.  Os dejo codigo de todo.

Muchísimas gracias

//issues.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Issue } from '../models/issues';
import { Global } from '../services/global';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IssueService{

  public url: string;

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { 
      this.url = Global.url;
    }

    getIssues():Observable<any>{
      return this._http.get(this.url+'repos/angular-slider/angularjs-slider/issues');
    }

}
```

//issues.ts (modelo)

```
export class Issue{
    constructor(
        public title: string,
        public avatar_url: string,
        public id: string,
        public login: string,
        public created_at: number,
    ){}
}
```

//issues.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { IssueService } from '../../services/issues.service';
import { Issue } from '../../models/issues';
import { Global } from '../../services/global';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-issues',
  templateUrl: './issues.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./issues.component.css'],
  providers: [IssueService]
})
export class IssuesComponent implements OnInit {

  public issues: Issue[] = [];
  public url: string;

  constructor(private _issueService: IssueService){
    this.url = Global.url;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._issueService.getIssues().subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.issues){
          this.issues = response.issues;
        }else{

        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }  
    )
  }
}
```

//issues.component.html

```
<ul class="list_issues">
<li *ngFor="let issue of issues" class="item_issues">
    <div class="avatar_issues">
      <div class="avatar-photo_issues">
        <img src='{{issue.owner.avatar_url}}'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="summary_issues">
      <a routerLink="/detail/{{issue.number}}">{{issue.title}}</a>
      <div class="id_summary">
        #123456 by
        <a href="">lalalal</a> created on Monday, June 15, 2020
        <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" width="16" height="16" aria-hidden="true">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 1H2c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v8c0 .55.45 1 1 1h2v3.5L7.5 11H14c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V2c0-.55-.45-1-1-1zm0 9H7l-2 2v-2H2V2h12v8z"></path>
        </svg>
        6
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, la forma en la que estas declarando tu modelo no es la correcta, te recomiendo aplicar las buenas prácticas y usar una interfaz, ejemplo:

```
interface Issue{
    title: string,
    avatar_url: string,
    id: string,
    login: string,
    created_at: number,   
}
```

Por otro lado, no te está mostrando nada porque al realizar la request http, esta se realiza de manera asincronica, por lo que cuando renderizas tu html, aún tus datos no están cargados. Tenes que mostrar tu lista cuando tus datos ya esten cargados, ejemplo:

```
<ul class="list_issues">
<div *ngIf="issues.length > 0"> //Aca renderizas solo cuando haya items en tu lista de issues
<li *ngFor="let issue of issues" class="item_issues">
    <div class="avatar_issues">
      <div class="avatar-photo_issues">
        <img src='{{issue.owner.avatar_url}}'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="summary_issues">
      <a routerLink="/detail/{{issue.number}}">{{issue.title}}</a>
      <div class="id_summary">
        #123456 by
        <a href="">lalalal</a> created on Monday, June 15, 2020
        <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" width="16" height="16" aria-hidden="true">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 1H2c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v8c0 .55.45 1 1 1h2v3.5L7.5 11H14c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V2c0-.55-.45-1-1-1zm0 9H7l-2 2v-2H2V2h12v8z"></path>
        </svg>
        6
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: No consigo que me muestre :( Estaré haciendo algo mal seguramente pero no se porque.

En la captura que envio ves que se me ve el array pero no tiene ningún nombre el array simplemente me pone (19). Debería de tener un nombre ?

A mi el nombre de delante del array no me aparace, puede ser por eso?